# Clustered Index Description

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index

I am aware that clustered indexes mimic the physical records in a table and nonclustered indexes access the data via an address in memory.  The term “pointer” is used quite a bit when describing non clustered indexes but would it be accurate to say clustered indexes point to the actual data.  Or is “pointing” only reserved when referring to nonclustered indexes?  I would think just “pointing to actual data” would be acceptable when describing clustered indexes because I’m not referring to memory addresses or a pointer itself.  I deal with indexes a lot at work and often provide explanations to junior-level colleagues.  I’ve used the above terminology before, but I’ve never been positive if the wording is correct.

Comment: This might improve your understanding of indexes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to grasp the concept of indexes is by comparing them to those used in real life.

A clustered index functions like an old fashioned phonebook, which is sorted by City, last name, first name. Meaning that if you need to find a record for Skiguy98 in Tulsa, and open up the book at Phoenix, you know you have to go forward. If the next page you open is for Valentine, you need to move backwards. Once you hit Tulsa, and find the page on which there's a record for SchmitzIT, you know you need to move down some more to reach the record for Skiguy98.

In other words, because there's a physical sorting mechanism taking place, it allows you to very quickly find what you are looking for. The implication of that, though, is that the index needs to be kept up-to-date, and occasionally needs defragmentation in order to remain optimized.

In comparison, a non-clustered index is like an index at the end of a book, which contains pointers to pages in a book that contain the term you are looking for. So if you are looking for "Clustered Indexes", that index will tell you you can find that term on pages 5, 25, 48 and 50. You then need to browse to those pages, and find the actual term on those pages.

If your table has no indexes at all, it's called a heap. The easiest way to think of that is you get a book that is just a collection of paper. All pages are shuffled in random order. Whenever doing a demonstration, I like having a stack of papers and tossing it on the floor, then telling participants to find all pages containing the term "Clustered Index", and going for a coffee.

Comment: I appreciate the background on indexes.  However, my question was primarily referring to the terminology I used when describing clustered indexes to my colleagues.  I know clustered indexes match the actual data, ordering and all.  But is saying a clustered index “points” to the actual data a stretch.  I’ve seen nonclustered indexes explained using pointers, so by simply using the term “points”, am I describing the clustered index incorrectly?

Comment: Well, it is correct to a point. A clustered index page can point to a data row on an index page, but it can also point to another index page. 

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-index-design-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#Clustered